# Isomorphism classes of étale $k$-algebras with dimension $n$ such that $A\otimes_k E$ is $E$-split étale and $H^1(\text{Gal}(E/k),S_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

For groups $G$, $H$, let $H^1(G,H)$ be the set of $H$-orbits in $\text{Hom}_{\text{Grp}}(G,H)$ under the right $H$-action  $(f\cdot a):g\mapsto a^{-1}f(g)a$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of a finite Galois extension $E/k$.
Consider the set $X_n$ of isomorphism classes of étale $k$-algebras $A$ with dimension $n$ such that $A\otimes_k E$ is a split étale $E$-algebra.
I would like to find a bijection between $X_n$ and $H^1(G,S_n)$.

By Grothendieck's Galois theory,
any $k$-algebra isomorphism $\phi:A\to B$ between said étale algebras uniquely corresponds to its pullback $\phi^*:\text{Hom}_{k-\text{alg}}(B,E)\to\text{Hom}_{k-\text{alg}}(A,E)$ between finite $G$-sets.
However, what exactly should be the map that maps the isomorphism class of $A$ to an orbit of $\text{Hom}_{\text{Grp}}(G,S_n)$?
I struggle to proceed here.

Comment: A homomorphism $G \to S_n$ is the same thing as the action of a group on a (fixed) set of size $n$, and a conjugacy class of such homomorphisms is the same thing as an isomorphism class of such actions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry if my question is dumb, but how does the isomorphism class of a $G$-action determines the isomorphism class of an étale $k$-algebra $A$ with dimension $n$ such that $A\otimes_k E$ is a split étale $E$-algebra? Is it just $(E^X)^G$, where $X$ is the conjugacy class?